# Существует ли в русском языке точный и краткий эквивалент академическому термину rubric?

Tags: терминология, переводы, термины

В академической среде термин означает "критерии оценки, стандарты для практики оценивания работ, руководство по оцениванию" и так далее, применяется, прежде всего, в активном обучении (active learning) для оценки выступлений, презентаций, и т. п..

[Здесь вики-статья на английском языке](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubric_(academic)) с раскрытием термина.

Comment: **Мерило** Но желательно чтобы Вы привели пример употребления.

Comment: Спасибо, но мерило вряд ли можно назвать устоявшимся академическим термином, применяемым в системе активного обучения.